# Android update gradle from AndroidStudio or CommandLine

Tags: java, android, gradle, command-line, proxy

as far our country boycotted with `Google` servers we must use `proxy` or `vpn`, since the last night i can't update `Gradle` repository with `AndroidStudio` or `CommandLine` but clicking on each `jar` files links in error messages, they can be download from browser such as `Firfox` or `Chrome`

links such as :

```
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.8.2/bundletool-1.8.2.jar
```

so i can't update `Gradle` from `AndroidStudio` and `CommandLine`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find bundletool-1.8.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.8.2/bundletool-1.8.2.jar
   > Could not find transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar
   > Could not find core-proto-0.0.8-alpha07.jar (com.google.testing.platform:core-proto:0.0.8-alpha07).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/testing/platform/core-proto/0.0.8-alpha07/core-proto-0.0.8-alpha07.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

now how can i solve this problem? BTW, in my `AndroidStudio` i set proxy to `auto detect proxy setting` before

Comment: I am experiencing a very similar error... did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @SMMH yes, you can use `shecan` 's dns easily :)